You do not have access to the workspace storage account. The storage account may be behind a VNET. Contact your administrator if this error persists
I have created the AML workspace and Storage account with virtual network but I'm getting this error while accessing the notebooks in the aml workspace:

Do we need to add any NSG rules or how to resolve this issue?
but In the AML Workspace > Connections (Under Manage) > able to create the blob storage container connections in the workspace.


created the AML workspace and Storage account without any virtual network but I'm getting this error while accessing the notebooks in the aml workspace:You do not have access to the workspace storage account. The storage account may be behind a VNET. Contact your administrator if this error persists.

According to this MS- Q&A by Vinodh247.
The above error indicates restricted access to the storage account associated with your Azure ML workspace, possibly due to VNet firewall rules.
To resolve this request your administrator to whitelist your IP/subnet, accessing via a VM on the same VNet, or creating a new ML workspace and storage account without VNet restrictions.
In portal, check the storage account which is linked with Azure ML workspace.
Portal:

Check the storage account networking section if the firewall is enabled or not manually from the portal.
If the networking is Disabled or Enabled from selected virtual networks and IP addresses you will get error in azure machine learn workspace.
Portal:
For sample, I changed my networking to disabled it showing same error as like yours in my environment.

Portal:
Now, I changed to Enabled from all networks in networking section it is showing notebook sample section successfully.

If your storage account firewall is enabled create a virtual machine with same vnet access from the virtual machine.
